# Jax-rs 405 error on put

Tags: java, html, rest, jax-rs, put

I use this method to update some resource

```
@PUT
@Path("/Updatemember/{nom}/{ape}/{afi}/{nac}")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String Updatemember(@PathParam("nom")String nombre, @PathParam("ape")String apellido, 
                            @PathParam("afi")String afiliacion, @PathParam("nac")String nacionalidad) throws SQLException
{
    Miembro.update(nombre, apellido, afiliacion, nacionalidad);
    return "Se han actualizado los datos del miembro";
}
```

But i get a 405 error when i try to invoke it .Should I pass the parameters  on the path or how I should do to make it work?
If I use @GET instead of @PUT works correctly.

Comment: Don't use path segments as resource state values. They should only be used as locators. Pass the values as a representation through the body of the request.

Comment: What on the server is causing the 405? Do you have a stacktrace or something?

Comment: Yes, 1) Look at the server log and show us the stacktrace. JAX-RS will throw an exception, which is mapped to that 405. 2) Show how you are accessing this resource (i.e. the client request)